# How can I move the legend of a plotly figure to the left without covering my graph?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have the following Plotly figure. I am using Dash to create a dashboard. I managed to move the legend to the left, but it is now covering a part of my actual graph. How can I avoid this?

[image: This is the graph]

Here is the code I used to create the figure and update its layout:

```
fig2=px.line(df_tradef2,x='Year', y='Value', title=Measures2+' - '+district2, color='Commodity',  width=1200, height=650)
fig2.update_xaxes(nticks=len(pd.unique(df_tradef2['Year'])), rangeslider_visible=True)
fig2.update_layout(yaxis_range=[start2,end2])
fig2.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="v",
    yanchor="auto",
    y=1,
    xanchor="auto",
    x=-0.3
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the anchoring point of the legend to `right`:

```py
fig2.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="v",
    yanchor="auto",
    y=1,
    xanchor="right",  # changed
    x=-0.3
    ))
```

This will make sure the right side of the legend box is at 30% to the left of the y-axis in [paper coordinates](https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/#positioning-with-paper-container-coordinates-or-axis-domain-coordinates).